# Haskell iteration (not literally) over a list

Tags: loops, haskell, functional-programming

I know I should be forgetting about iterating in functional languages, but I dont know how else to put forth my question.

If I have a list of integers arranged in ascending or descending order, and I have an arbitrary number that may or may not be present in the list, how can I loop over the list to find a number that is small than the given number and return that integer.

I just need to know how to go about it.

Comment: Does the [`elem` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) work for you?

Comment: You recurse, as usual.

Comment: @user5402 No, `elem` doesn't do what OP asked for.

Comment: Show some of your attempts.

Comment: You should give a concrete example - e.g. input and expected output.

Comment: I have thought of different algorithms, but none seems to be feasible as I cannot maintain a state

Comment: List [1,3,4,5,6,7,99,122,333]...Input is 55...Output 7

Comment: What if the list is empty? What if there isn't a number greater than the input?

Comment: List will always have [1] in it. Return the input if there is no larger number

Comment: your requirements seem inconsistent: [1,7,99] 55 should return 7, but [1,7] 55 should return 55?? The consistent thing to do would be to return 7 in the latter case too.

Comment: to return the largest number in the list not greater than the input number, `last . takeWhile (<= input) $ xs`. To accommodate your latest requirement, `let (a,b)=span(<= input) xs in head $ [input|null b]++[last a]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` to find the first element matching a predicate you specify. Example:

```
find even [3,5,7,6,2,3,4]
```

Or, you could drop all the unwanted elements from the left:

```
dropWhile (not . even) [3,5,7,6,2,3,4]
```

(and possibly take the first element remaining, which has to be even).

Or, you could filter out unwanted elements

```
filter even [3,5,7,6,2,3,4]
```

Or, you could use recursion and code everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively deconstruct the list with pattern matching:

```
searchList :: Int -> [Int] -> ???
searchList n [] = ??? 
searchList n (x:xs) = ???
```

You check whether x is the number you want, and if not you can call `searchList n xs` to search the rest of the list.

The normal way to do something like that would be with the library function `foldr`, but it would be better to understand how to do this with recursion first.

Comment: I think it would be useful to point out that you can also match more than one element and that you can use guards `searchList n (x:y:xs) | <condition with x y and n>`

Answer (score 0):

You can have "state" in a list iteration by using a fold - the state is passed from one iteration to the next in a function argument.

An example:

```
sup :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
sup xs y = go (head xs) xs
  where
    go s [] = s
    go s (x:xs) = if x >= y then s else go x xs
```

Here `s` is the "state" -- it is the latest value in the list that is less than `y`.

Because you said the input list would never be empty, `head xs` is okay here.

This is almost what you want. Perhaps you can modify it to handle all of your conditions.